# Python: Using popen poll on background process

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen, subprocess

I am running a long process (actually another python script) in the background. I need to know when it has finished. I have found that `Popen.poll()` always returns 0 for a background process. Is there another way to do this?

```
p = subprocess.Popen("sleep 30 &", shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
a = p.poll()
print(a)
```

Above code never prints `None`.

Comment: You are using the shell backgrounding syntax (`&`), which makes the sub-process starts a sub-sub-process and then exit itself -- this is why you get `0` (process finished) rather than `None` (still running)

Answer (score 49):

You don't need to use the shell backgrounding `&` syntax, as `subprocess` will run the process in the background by itself

Just run the command normally, then wait until `Popen.poll` returns `not None`

```
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("sleep 30", shell=True)
# Better: p = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "30"])

# Wait until process terminates
while p.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)

# It's done
print("Process ended, ret code:", p.returncode)
```

Answer (score 15):

I think you want either the `popen.wait()` or `popen.communicate()` commands. Communicate will grab the `stdout` and `stderr` data which you've put into `PIPE`. If the other item is a Python script I would avoid running a `shell=True` call by doing something like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([python.call, "my", params, (go, here)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

Of course these hold the main thread and wait for the other process to complete, which might be bad. If you want to busy wait then you could simply wrap your original code in a loop. (Your original code did print "None" for me, btw)

Example of the wrapping in a loop solution:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([python.call, "my", params, (go, here)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while p.poll() == None:
    # We can do other things here while we wait
    time.sleep(.5)
    p.poll()
(results, errors) = p.communicate()
if errors == '':
    return results
else:
    raise My_Exception(errors)
```

Comment: Cleaned up my loop example based on dbr's great answer (totally forgot to add a sleep call to avoid thrashing)

Comment: This answer stays in the poll loop for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't run your script with ampersand at the end. Because shell forks your process and returns 0 exit code.