# Check if a subprocess is running in Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have an environment variable that allows a suite of applications to run under certain conditions, and the applications cannot run with the environment variable off.

My python script uses

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdStr3,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

to open the subprocess.

To test if the application is running, I have tried

```
try:
    os.kill(pid, 0)
    return True
except OSError:
    return False
```

and also checking `p.returncode`. However, these always return true, because even if the application doesn't pull up on the screen, there are mini processes of ~1 MB that still run without the application fully running, so the os sees these and returns true. Is there a way around this?

Another issue is that `os.kill` doesn't work, the only way I have found to terminate the application is `os.killpg` at the end.

What I've learned from the comments is that what actually happens is that the subprocess I call is a starter that calls a child which is another application. My subprocess always runs, but with the environment variable off, the child application does not run. Is there a way to see if the child is running?

Comment: What do you mean by 'miniprocesses'? If `pid` can be found, the program exists and is running, right?

Comment: You can use `p.terminate()` to stop the child process and `p.poll()` to check if it is still running.

Comment: @Evert you're right. I guess what actually happens is that the subprocess I call is a starter that calls a child which is another application. My subprocess always runs, but with the environment variable off, the child application does not run. Is there a way to see if the child is running?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like `ps`, assuming those sub-child processes have a unique name. Otherwise, if the starter process doesn't keep track of the child, I think all bets are off (you could search for orphan processes, but there may be plenty).

Comment: I will look into `ps`. For all the cases I've tested, the child application always has a process ID that is one more than the subprocess. Will this always be the case or is this a foolish way to check

Comment: Well let me tell you, it's foolish.

Comment: It seems your question is: how to find out whether a **grandchild** process is alive. Update your question, to make it clear that `p.poll()` that reports whether a **child** process is alive is not applicable in your case (because your comments suggest that the *child* continues to run whether grandchild is alive or not).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`p.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check if the process is still running.

> *Another issue is that os.kill doesn't work, the only way I have found to terminate the application is os.killpg at the end.*

If you want to kill a process launched using subprocess, you can use [`p.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate).

Finally, if you want to *wait* until the process child dies, you can use [`p.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Comment: Can you please add an example of how to use p.poll?

Comment: you can find an example on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057794/python-using-popen-poll-on-background-process/12058609#12058609 ☺